# How can I calculate the power of two with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I want to use *Geometry Nodes* to calculate some integer values, but just can't find the solution to the following problem:

| Initial Value | Target Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |
| 6 | 64 |
| 7 | ... |

Does any genius math brain have an idea?

Comment: Shouldn't input=0 result in output=1? (2^0=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
[image]

You can use the math/power node for this.

Comment: You re welcome. :) Sometime, we looking for the more complex way. I know that so many Time... :/